# Writable registry permission

Tags: c#, registry

```
 RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();

 RegistryKey rk =
 RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32).
 OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\MyApplication", true);

 rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule("Everyone",
 RegistryRights.WriteKey | RegistryRights.ReadKey | RegistryRights.Delete,
                        InheritanceFlags.None,
                        PropagationFlags.None,
                        AccessControlType.Allow));
```

I am trying to give writable permission to all system  user for particular folder under SOFTWARE from registry. but i couldnt do this using C# code. please let me out from this fix.

Comment: Did you mean "registry key" instead of "folder"?

Comment: Also, what is your problem?

Comment: actually i am trying to give fullcontroll for particular folder alone under software but i cant do it and above the code not do anything??!!

Answer (score 3):

//Complete solution:

```
        RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
        RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\ASUS", true);
        rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule("Everyone", RegistryRights.WriteKey |  RegistryRights.ReadKey, InheritanceFlags.None, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Deny)); 
        if(rk != null)
        {
          rk.SetAccessControl(rs);
        }
```

Comment: i tried with rk.setAccessContro;(rs) also but exception showing as "System.NullRefernceException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object". what i do now???

Comment: RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
RegistryKey rk =RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\ASUS", true);
rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule("Everyone",
                            RegistryRights.WriteKey | RegistryRights.ReadKey,
                            InheritanceFlags.None,
                            PropagationFlags.None,
                            AccessControlType.Deny));
                rk.SetAccessControl(rs);
                MessageBox.Show("success");

Comment: great! now its (AccessControlType.Deny) working fine but when i change it into (AccessControlType.Allow) its showing exception as System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.even i am doing this in admin login only.please help me out!

Comment: The only reason you'll get this exception is when you dont have permissions to change the key. got to registry and check the permissions by right clicking on the key and select permissions on pop up menu.